# SCSS Loader not found Laravel 5.3 VueJS

Tags: webpack, laravel-elixir, vuejs2

In my .Vue template i'm defining a  tag, however every time i try to compile it says

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'scss-loader'

I'm using Laravel 5.3's default implementation of Vue JS is there anything i'm missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably missing it and potentially node-sass as dependencies in your package.json. Try running the below in the root of your project:

`npm install sass-loader node-sass --save-dev`

**EDIT**

Use sass as the type

Comment: thank you for your help, apparently in Laravel the default loader for SCSS is 'sass' not 'scss' that was my problem, if i say `<style lang='sass'>` it works

Comment: No worries if you want to mark it as answered that would be awesome